# Zendesk - CreateUser JobStatus Results is Null

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

So I am currently working with the ZenDesk API. I am creating many users using the batch CreateUser method that takes an array of up to 100 user objects. Now, for some reason, some users fail to generate. Therefore, I wanted to obtain the result of the JobStatus after creating the users so that I can identify the problem easily. The issue is that the result variable is null after performing the CreateUsers() method.

Some sample code:

```
public static void createEndUsers(Zendesk zd){      
    for(Organization org : zd.getOrganizations()){
        List<User> usersList = getUsersPerOrg(org, 0)
        JobStatus js = zd.createUsers(usersList);

        List<T> resultElements = js.getResults(); 
    }
}
```

Why is getResults() returning null in this instance? Is it because the operation has not yet been performed when it reaches that part of the code? How can I make sure that I "wait" until the result is ready before I try to access it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the posssible values from `org.zendesk.client.v2.model.JobStatus.JobStatusEnum` you will notice that the job may be queued for execution or it could still be running at the time that the job status was returned by the operation `org.zendesk.client.v2.Zendesk#createUsers(org.zendesk.client.v2.model.User...)`.

As can be seen from the [Zendesk Documentation for createUsers Operation](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/users#create-or-update-many-users)

> This endpoint returns a job_status JSON object and queues a background job to do the work. Use the Show Job Status endpoint to check for the job's completion.

only when the job is completed, there will be a corresponding result delivered for the operation.

A possible solution in your case would be to check (possibly in a separate thread) every 500ms whether the job status is not queued or not running (otherwise said whether it completed) and if it successfully completed to retrieve the results.